# Converting 1,4-benzenedimethanol to benzene and methanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, alcohols

I have the molecule 1,4-benzenedimethanol:

[image]

How could I produce two methanol molecules and one benzene molecule? (Is there a catalytic reaction method available for this?)
I'm guessing that hydrogen ions could be used to split off the methanol molecules on both sides?

Answer (score 3):

Oxidize to the dialdehyde (Jones reagent), decarbonylate with rhodium (do it at the bench before building the pilot plant), reduce the CO to methanol.  Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I will not ask why you would want to do that.

You're right that the benzylic alkohol can be deprotonated. But that won't help you for the intended reaction.

Regarding the possible mechanisms, I suggest to do it on paper.

Draw the starting material and split the bonds. Draw the fragments that result from splitting the $\ce{Ph\bond{-}CH2OH}$ bond. Do this first for the two heterolytical pathways possible in theory. Inspect the fragments and ask yourself, how stable these might be in general, and in the presence of other molecules of the starting material.

Are they likely? ;)

Compare with the following experiment on paper: Which reactions are possible with your starting material in the presence of strong acids? (Assuming that their corresponding bases are lousy nucleophiles.) Yes, it has nothing to do with the reaction you'd like to perform. But it works ;)

Now let's inspect the homolytical case.

To cut the "lecture" short, it has indeed been observed that [benzylic alcohol furnishes benzene upon sonication (PDF)](http://cpb.pharm.or.jp/cpb/200009/C09_1299.pdf). The yields however are only in the ppm range and I'm not aware of a comparable study on the title compound.

---

Edit:

Concerning the question in your last comment, have a look at the prices for methanol and benzene at the chemical supplier of your choice:

Methanol (z.S.)         2,5 l   14.00 €

Benzene  (reinst)       1,0 l   32.90 €

1,4-Benzenedimethanol   50 g  294.30 €

Let's just say that the production of methanol and benzene the way you suggested is not a promising concept.

Comment: thanks :) (My organic chemistry knowledge is not very good) but would it be possible to create other organic molecules, derived from this molecule that then can be eventually reacted to form methanol and another compound?